# OAuth2 library for Google Apps: callback function not found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

I am trying to use "[OAuth2 library for Google Apps](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2)" in my "Apps Script".
It works (I see dialog box, etc.) but in the end I get error message "callback function authCallback not found". How to fix this problem?

```
var clientId = "clientId";
var clientSecret = "clientSecret";

function authCallback(request) {  
  var isAuthorized = service.handleCallback(request);  
  if( isAuthorized ){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  } 
}

var service = OAuth2.createService("My");
service.setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth');
service.setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
service.setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher');
service.setClientId(clientId);
service.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
service.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
service.setCallbackFunction('authCallback');
service.setParam('access_type', 'offline');
service.setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

if(!service.hasAccess()) {
  showSidebar();
}else{
  console.log( "AccessToken: "+service.getAccessToken() );
}

function showSidebar(){
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
          '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a>. ' +
          'Reopen the sidebar when the authorization is complete.');

  var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
  template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
  var page = template.evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);
}
```

Comment: Can you post a Screenshot or explain where the error is being shown? As you have the function in the code, it seems weird that this does not work. Or you can also go through the console and see what it is logging out.

Comment: I think your code snippet is not complete - everything related to `service` is placed outside of a funciton. Also, it is not clear which is the funciton that gives you the error message and how you call it.

Comment: @ziganotschka My code is working, I can log in, but fail in the end. I create it by official documentation.

Comment: @Neven Subotic There is no any errors in console. I see dialog box and can log in without error but finally I see window "function not found" and can not continue.

Comment: What do you mean by "log-in"? I cannot see how you call the dialog, neither what happens in the dialog - the client-side function fo your code. It is hard to troubleshoot without all the necessary information.

Comment: @ziganotschka please see screen shots

Comment: I think the problem is the freestanding code block. Try to pass the `service` creation into a function and call this function whenever you would like to use the service object.

Comment: @ziganotschka I solved the problem. This is my fault, the source code was not full, but thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I define functions as nested into script function `myFunction()`.
This is works for function `showSidebar()` but function `authCallback(request)` must be in the root as external.